# ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cli

I'm currently trying to deploy a Django 1.7, Python 3.4 WebApp to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I'm following the guide on the AWS site, but when I try using their config files in the .ebextensions directory, the line "option_name: WSGIPath" seems to give me the error "ERROR: Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath"

Comment: Hey, could you post your .ebextensions file here?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on `eb create` command, but I solved this problem a moment ago.

It's because I have selected the incorrect option ( **fourth** ) while I executing `eb init` command on CLI,

```
Select a platform version.
1) Python 3.4
2) Python 2.7
3) Python
4) Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker)
(default is 1): 4
```

So I started the sample project again, At this time I just selected **the first**, then I was able to finish the AWS guide.